# How do I work with appended divs?

Tags: jquery

I'm a massive newbie to jquery so please excuse my lack of knowledge, how do I go about doing anything with the elements i've appended here? for instance I want to have all but the first '.larger' to be hidden when these elements are appended. thanks.

```
function loadXML()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XML_PATH,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var images = $(this).find('large').text();
                    var thumbs = $(this).find('thumb').text();
                    var descs = $(this).find('description').text();
                    $('<div class="thumber" id="thumb_'+id+'" rel="large_'+id+'" style="background-image: url('+thumbs+')"></div>').appendTo('#thumbslide');
                    $('<div class="larger" id="large_'+id+'" style="background-image: url('+images+')"></div>').appendTo('#view');
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no point in doing $(this) 4 times. you're slowing down your code by doing that.  It would be more efficient to store/cache that.

`var $this = $(this);`

To do what you want you could do something like this...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            var first = true;
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var id = $this.attr('id');
                var images = $this.find('large').text();
                var thumbs = $this.find('thumb').text();
                var descs = $this.find('description').text();
                $('<div class="thumber" id="thumb_'+id+'" rel="large_'+id+'" style="background-image: url('+thumbs+')"></div>').appendTo('#thumbslide').toggle(!first);
                $('<div class="larger" id="large_'+id+'" style="background-image: url('+images+')"></div>').appendTo('#view').toggle(!first);
                first = false;
            });
});
```

With jQuery you can just continue to chain operations.

Comment: I think `.hide(!first)` is not correct. Parameter to the function is a duration, to animate the hiding, not a boolean to hide or not ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)).

Comment: You are correct, I have updated my code to use toggle instead.

Comment: thanks for your help, this was useful. however, I have designs on making something much bigger. I want a way of accessing my appended content globally, what i really wish could be done would be to use an id selector, something equivalent to using $('#large_'+i). is there a way to make the appended elements as workable as the dom elements?

Answer (score 1):

The call back function of the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method has actually two params, the current index and the current dom element:

```
.each(function(index, element))
```

You can do it when creating the element:

```
$('<div class="larger" id="large_'+id+'" style="background-image: url('+images+')"></div>')
// apply css 'block' for first item, otherwise 'none' to hide
.css('display', index === 0 ? 'block' : 'none')
.appendTo('#view')
```

Comment: thanks for your help, this was useful. however, I have designs on making something much bigger. I want a way of accessing my appended content globally, what i really wish could be done would be to use an id selector, something equivalent to using $('#large_'+i). is there a way to make the appended elements as workable as the dom elements?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that hides all ".larger" elements except the first:

```
$(".larger").not(":first").hide();
```